# How to remove square brackets with using multiple marking groups within each line of a text file?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I can't figure out how to use group matches for replacement.

Here is my issue: I have an sql file I want to modify in order to make it mysql compatible.

The file looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Client ([name], [id], [company]) VALUES ('Roger', 1, '[Coca-cola]');  
INSERT INTO Client ([name], [id], [company]) VALUES ('Lisa', 2, '[Nike]');
```

I want it to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Client (name, id, company) VALUES ('Roger', 1, '[Coca-cola]');  
INSERT INTO Client (name, id, company) VALUES ('Lisa', 2, '[Nike]');
```

I managed to write this regex:

```
\\((\\[([^\\]]*)\\],? ?)+\\) VALUES
```

I am using sublimetext3. It is using the [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) regex library.
But I don't know what to write for the replacement string.

Any ideas?

PS: The original file has several different tables with different number of rows and has 13000 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
(?<=\(|, )\[|\](?=,|\))
```

Replace the matched brackets with an empty string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/21)

Comment: Thanks @Avinash. That would work using the example I have given. But I have several tables with different columns number..

Comment: Could you edit your answer so that I refers to the right solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the search string `(?<!')\[|\](?!')` and an empty string as replace string.

Explanation:

`(?<!')` ... a negative lookbehind for character `'`.

`\[` ... literal character `[`.

`|` ... OR expression.

`\]` ... literal character `]`.

`(?!')` ... a negative lookahead expression for character `'`.

Find an opening square bracket not preceded by a single quote OR a closing square bracket with next character not being a single quote.

Comment: thanks @Mofi that is much smarter!  
But that would erase brackets in data. For instance if I had a company name 'Good bye =] smiley'